# using printf in a macro supporting multiple types

Tags: c++

I have a macro like this:

```
#define assert_cmp(a, cmp, b) \
    if(!((a) cmp (b))) { \
        std::cerr << "Assertion failed: " << a << " " << #cmp << " " << b << std::endl; \
        assert((a) cmp (b)); \
    }
```

(Yes, I maybe should do a `do { ... } while(0)` around that...)

Then I can use this for example like:

```
void f(int a) {
    assert_cmp(a, <=, 42);
    // ...
}
```

That works fine. Now however, I want to use the same macro also for some CUDA code, and I can only use `printf` there. (CUDA is not really relevant to the question, just that I must use `printf`.)

How can I translate the macro to use `printf` instead of `std::cerr`? This is not so simple, because the arguments `a` and `b` can be of any type (although it is fine if we only care about numeric types now).

Maybe like this:

```
#define assert_cmp(a, cmp, b) \
    if(!((a) cmp (b))) { \
        printf("Assertion failed: "); \
        printf(_format_for_type(a), a); \
        printf(" " #cmp " "); \
        printf(_format_for_type(b), b); \
        printf("\n"); \
        assert((a) cmp (b)); \
    }

template<typename T>
const char* _format_for_type(const T&);

template<> const char* _format_for_type(const int&) { return "%i"; }
template<> const char* _format_for_type(const float&) { return "%f"; }

...
```

Comment: Nothing in this question looks like C. Are you sure that the tag is helpful?

Comment: *Maybe like this* - What's the problem with that approach? Btw, I'm quite sure you can use IO-streams with the later versions of CUDA.

Comment: Will double '#' + double expansion help? (e.g. https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2008/12/20/expanding-macros-into-string-constants-in-c/)

Comment: @Yunnosch: I don't know. I thought because I use macros which is kind of C style. Although I don't know any good way to accomplish something similar in C++ (without making it too complicated). But maybe we can remove the tag.

Comment: @Swordfish: I don't know yet. That was a spontaneous idea while writing the question. I'm trying right now. But maybe someone else knows a better way. Also, for the `std::cerr` version, I get some CUDA errors that I cannot call a host function. And I know that `printf` works in any case.

Comment: @thebjorn: It might help to print the C++ expression string, which also can be helpful for debugging purpose, but I also want to print the value (just equivalent to my original version with `std::cerr`).

Comment: is it `std::cerr` restriction or just any streams? in the former case, just use `std::stringstream` to prepare your output and then use `printf`

Comment: @Dmitry: Hm I thought about that, but actually I don't know what is allowed and what not. Maybe I should put the CUDA tag. But e.g. I think `malloc` etc are not allowed, and pretty sure that `stringstream` internally will alloc sth.

Comment: It isn't quite clear why `_format_for_type` would be allowed where `<<` isn't. If things like `_format_for_type` are allowed, why not just call `_print_for_type` instead?

Comment: @n.m. The problem is probably not `<<`, the problem is `std::cerr`. `std::cerr << sth;` does lots of things. I didn't really debugged why this does not work. But `_format_for_type` on the other side has no dependencies at all, so of course that works always (on CUDA, you should put `__host__ __device__` there of course).

Comment: @Albert Why do you want to use `printf()` instead of `std::cerr`?

Comment: Doesn't `assert()` already print an error message that contains the condition? If I do `assert(1 > 2);`, then the program aborts with `int main(): Assertion '1 > 2' failed.` It seems you are just duplicating the error message. In fact, your `assert_cmp` macro is just duplicating the `assert()` function... Why do you need this macro to begin with? Can't you just use `assert()` directly?

Comment: @NikosC. No. As said, I want the same behavior as before. E.g. `assert(a > 2)` would print sth like Assertion 'a > 2' failed. That is not helpful. My original behavior would print what the value of `a` is.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I translate the macro to use printf instead of std::cerr?

That's impossible to do generally, because `printf` supports only a limited count of specifiers and length sub-specifiers. In other words, there are types that can be printed with `operator<<`, but can't with `printf`.

You could do `std::ostringstream ss; ss << stuff; printf("%s", ss.str());`.

> Maybe like this:

Yes, like this, this is a great approach that allows to control and at compile time detect any problems. I see no value in creating the format string, just print the value. I would not create a format string, but instead just output the value, which would allow to create overloads for custom types.

```
template<typename T> void myprint(const T&);
template<> void myprint(const int& v) { printf("%i", v); }
template<> void myprint(const float& v) { printf("%f", v); }
// custom types
class MyData {
    int a;
    int b;
    template<typename T> friend void myprint(const T &v);
};
template<> void myprint(const MyData& v) {
    printf("%d %d", v.a, v.b);
}

#define assert_cmp(a, cmp, b) \
    ... myprint(a); ...
```